# Assigning relevant splash screens in config.xml for PhoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, config

I am currently developing an application using PhoneGap for multiple devices. How do we configure it in config.xml so that we can specify the size of splash screen (and matter of fact for icons) for the different devices (e.g. iPhone, iPad, Android)?

Answer (score 0):

For Android:
design relevant Splash and icon images and drop them in respective drawables (drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc ..) folders

For iPhone:
Just select Default.png images in your XCode for both iPhone and iPad